# How to determine an iterating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm curious if there is a general method to computing the "iterator function" (not sure if this is the correct name, but is what I am calling it) of a recurrence relation.

Specifically, given a recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
h(1) & n = 1\\
T(f(n)) + h(n) & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I'm interested in find a function $g(k)$ such that $g(k) = n$ and $f(g(k)) = g(k-1)$. With this new function we can create an equivalent recurrence $S(k) = T(g(k))$:
$$S(k) = \begin{cases}
h(1) & g(k) = 1\\
S(k-1) + h(g(k)) & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Alternatively you could consider that I'm looking for a function $g(k)$ such that $g(k-i) = f^{(i)}(n)$ where $f^{(i)}(n)$ is the application of $f$ on $n$, $i$ times (e.g. $f^{(3)}(n) = f(f(f(n)))\ $).

This can then be easily be converted into a summation:
$$T(n) = S(k) = \sum_{k = g^{-1}(1)}^{g^{-1}(n)} h(g(k))$$

The idea comes from my other answer over [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105833/68251). I am not sure of a general approach to finding the iterator $g(k)$. I have mostly found them through trial an error.

---

A simple example is:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 2\\
T(\sqrt{n}) + \log \log n & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then we have the iterating function be $g(k) = 2^{2^k}$ and then this translates into an equivalent recurrence $S(k) = T(2^{2^k}) = T(n)$:

$$S(k) = \begin{cases}
1 & k = 1\\
S(k-1) + k & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then we can easily see $S(k) = \sum_{i = 1}^k i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. We then work backwards to determine $T(n)$ as:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & = T(g(k))\\
& = S(k)\\
& = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\
& = \frac{g^{-1}(n)(g^{-1}(n) + 1)}{2}\\
& = \frac{\log \log n (1 + \log \log n)}{2}
\end{align*}$$

---

You can also assume $f(n)$ is monotone decreasing.

Comment: @Somos, very cool! This might be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking through wiki and citations, but do you know if there is literature on how to produce these for a given $f$ or given class of $f$'s ?

Comment: The Wikipedia [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation) article states "Even in the case of a single variable, the equation is non-trivial, and admits special analysis". In general you are out of luck unless it is a special known case.

Comment: @Somos, is there an equivalence between the +1 case (as shown in Wiki) and the -1 case that I am asking about? Given $f$ is monotone decreasing, it seems this should help some (maybe?).

Comment: Sorry. No difference. $f(g(k)) = g(k-1)$ with $h(x):=g(-x)$ becomes $f(h(-x))=h(1-x)$ or $f(h(x))=h(x+1)$.

Comment: @Somos anyway, I think this answers my question... unfortunately. Not sure how to award a bounty to a comment.

Comment: Don't sweat it. I could just add an answer now, but it is not the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a proper $g(\cdot)$ we have

$$
T(g(g^{-1}(n))) = T(g(g^{-1}(f(n))))+h(n)
$$

so with $T' = T(g())$ follows

$$
T'(g^{-1}(n))=T'(g^{-1}(f(n)))+h(n)
$$

now making $k = g^{-1}(n)$ we can consider two trivial soluble cases.

$$
g^{-1}(f(n)) = \begin{cases}g^{-1}(n)+m\\
mg^{-1}(n)\end{cases}
$$

giving

$$
T'(k) = T'(k+m) + h(g(k))\\
T'(k) = T'(mk)+h(g(k))
$$

The second case can be easily reduced by choosing $g^{-1}(k) = \log_m k$ giving

$$
T''(u) = T''(u+1) + h(g(m^u))
$$

with $u = \log_m k$

In any of those two cases, the return to $T$ is trivial

Comment: This brings up the almost equivalent question of "How do you find $g^{-1}(\cdot)$?". You propose two trivial cases for $g^{-1}(\cdot)$, but this only works after you've already found the $g$ or $g^{-1}$. For instance, if I gave you $$T(n) = T(2^{\sqrt{\log \log (n + 2)}}) + 2n \log n$$, it's still unclear how you would solve this.

Comment: No doubt that I can invent much more rugged cases, but this is not the case. The important thing is to try to limit certain families of problems that are resolvable.